# Knight's Tour with accessibility heuristic

Tags: java, knights-tour

Currently I'm just going through Deitels "Java, how to program early objects. 10th Edition". Exercise 7.22c) asks me to start using heuristic accessibility. d) Asks me to develop the app a tad further, and add a prediction to the next move in case of a tie. 
My problem is this. The program in c) already completes a full tour every single time, wherever I start. Is this the correct behaviour with a simple accessibility matrix? I would think the enhancement in d) was there to allow the program to really shine. Here's the code:

```
/* Exercise 7.22: Knight's Tour
 * See page 345
 */

package exercises;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise7_22 {

private static int[][] chessBoard = new int[8][8];
private static int currentRow;
private static int currentColumn;
private final static int[] horizontal = {2, 1, -1, -2, -2, -1, 1, 2};
private final static int[] vertical = {-1, -2, -2, -1, 1, 2, 2, 1};
private final static Random randomNumbers = new Random();
private final static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
private static int counter;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int row = 0; row < chessBoard.length; row++) {
        for(int col = 0; col < chessBoard[row].length; col++) {
            chessBoard = new int[8][8];
            currentRow = row;
            currentColumn = col;
            System.out.printf("Starting at %dx-%dy.%n", currentRow, currentColumn);
            int[][] accessability =
                {{2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2},
                 {3, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 3},
                 {4, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 6, 4},
                 {4, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 6, 4},
                 {4, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 6, 4},
                 {4, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 6, 4},
                 {3, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 3},
                 {2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2}};
            counter = 0;
            int min;
            ArrayList<Integer> surroundings = new ArrayList<>();

            do {
                surroundings.clear();
                min = 8;
                /* In case of finding a tile accessible by less spaces than the last least accessible tile, set it as the new
                 * least accessible tile but also alter the ArrayList accordingly. 
                 * In case of finding a tile as accessible as the current least accessible one, just add it to the list.
                 */
                for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                    if(canMove(i, false) && accessability[currentRow + vertical[i]][currentColumn + horizontal[i]] >= 0) {
                        if(accessability[currentRow + vertical[i]][currentColumn + horizontal[i]] < min) {
                            surroundings.clear();
                            min = accessability[currentRow + vertical[i]][currentColumn + horizontal[i]];
                            surroundings.add(i);
                        } else if(accessability[currentRow + vertical[i]][currentColumn + horizontal[i]] == min)
                            surroundings.add(i);        
                    }
                }
                if(surroundings.size() > 0) {
                    move(moveWhere(surroundings), accessability);
                    //drawBoard(accessability);
//                      try {
//                          Thread.sleep(1000);
//                      }catch (Exception e) {
//                          // TODO: handle exception
//                      }
                }
            } while(surroundings.size() > 0);
            drawBoard(chessBoard);
            System.out.println(counter);
        }
    }
//      System.out.print("Please enter a direction to move: ");
//      while(input.hasNext()) {
//          counter++;
//          int direction = input.nextInt();
//          while(!move(direction)) {
//              System.out.print("Please try moving somewhere else: ");
//              direction = input.nextInt();
//          }
//          drawBoard();
//          System.out.print("Please enter a new direction to move: ");
//      }
//      System.out.println(counter);

}
/* Method canMove determines
 * a) whether the knight moves within the confines of the board and if the next tile hasn't been occupied earlier.
 * b) in case where one is altering the accessibility matrix, simply if the knight is moving within the board.
 */
public static boolean canMove(int number, boolean accessability) {
    if(currentRow + vertical[number] < chessBoard.length 
            && currentRow + vertical[number] >= 0
            && currentColumn + horizontal[number] < chessBoard[currentColumn].length
            && currentColumn + horizontal[number] >= 0) {
        if(!accessability && chessBoard[currentRow + vertical[number]][currentColumn + horizontal[number]] == 0)
            return true;
        else if(accessability)
            return true;
    } 
        //System.out.printf("Could not move Knight to %dx-%dy.%n", 
        //      currentRow + vertical[number], currentColumn + horizontal[number]);
        return false;
}

/* After having made a successful call to canMove and having determined, in case of a tie,
 * which move to perform, the knight is moved to it's new location, at which point the accessibility
 * matrix is also altered. 
 */
public static void move(int number, int[][] accessability) {
    //System.out.printf("Knight moving from %dx-%dy ", currentColumn, currentRow);
    currentRow += vertical[number];
    currentColumn += horizontal[number];
    accessability[currentRow][currentColumn] = -1;
    alterAccessability(accessability);
    chessBoard[currentRow][currentColumn] = ++counter;
    //System.out.printf("to %dx-%dy.%n", currentColumn, currentRow);
}

/* In case of a tie amongst several tiles (due to the accessibility heuristics) the 
 * program chooses a move at random.
 */
public static int moveWhere(ArrayList<Integer> surroundings) {
    return surroundings.get(randomNumbers.nextInt(surroundings.size()));
}

/* This method alters the correct tiles around the knight's current position
 * after a call to canMove().
 */
public static void alterAccessability(int[][] accessability) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        if(canMove(i, true) && accessability[currentRow + vertical[i]][currentColumn + horizontal[i]] > 0) {
            accessability[currentRow + vertical[i]][currentColumn + horizontal[i]]--;
        }               
    }
}

public static void drawBoard(int[][] board) {
    for(int row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
        for(int col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++) {
            if(row == currentRow && col == currentColumn)
                System.out.print(" K  ");
            else
                System.out.printf(" %02d ", board[row][col]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

}

Comment: What do you want to achive?

Comment: I'm just curious whether making the code predictive by 1 move will in any way improve it? It clearly completes any tour fully as is and thus I'm curious whether the problem in d) is only there to give me some extra insight in case I'd like to make an actual chess game in the future, where I'm imagining recursive calls for the AI will be a must.